# docker compose can't pull image from google container registory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-container-registry

I have images on google container registry moved from docker hub. I have my docker-compose.yml. compose file is successfully pull the images from docker hub. But I can't pull from google container registry.

step to login to container registry

1. gcloud auth revoke --all
2. gcloud auth login
3. gcloud config set project projectId
4. gcloud auth activate-service-account deploy@projectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=service-account.json
5. gcloud auth configure-docker
6. (a) gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://asia.gcr.io

Login Result is success

docker-compose up

```
ERROR: pull access denied for [my_image_name], repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I can pull the image with below command

```
docker pull asia.gcr.io/projectid/myimagename/data-api:latest
```

docker compose

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  data_api:
    container_name: myimagename-data-api
    image: myimagename/data-api
    expose:
      - 4000
    ports:
      - "4001:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:root@db:3306/myimagename
      ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: xxxxxxxxxx
      REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET: xxxxxxxxx
    networks:
      - db-api

  db:
    container_name: myimagename-db
    image: myimagename/db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db/data/:/var/lib/mariadb/data
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MARIADB_DATABASE: myimagename
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - db-api

networks:
  db-api:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `service-account.json` file, you will see that it's not your "password" in the traditional sense.  Hence piping it in as a stdin password will not work.  EDIT: TIL - you **can** pipe a credentials file in as a password as per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key)

I would recommend using the [gcloud credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud-helper) -- you can login as yourself if you have the perms or you can use a service account with its credentials.json file -- which appears to be your case there.  Be sure to have the correct IAM perms on your service account.

Pull (read) only:

- roles/storage.objectViewer

Push (write) and Pull:

- roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter

Comment: Happy New Year and thank for reply. After I follow gcloud credential, I can pull the image using gcloud container registry command but I till can't pull the image using docker compose. I have added docker compose in my question. Do I need to change anything in my docker-compose.yml?

Comment: oh!  You need to include the gcr.io in your image path inside your docker-compose.yaml:

image: asia.gcr.io/projectid/myimagename/data-api

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Finally, I found the issue. It is image name. We can not use same image name as docker hub. we need full path.

image: asia.gcr.io/projectid/myimagename/data-api:latest

instead of myimagename/data-api

Comment: LOL -- i just looked over your docker-compose file and I saw the same thing.   In any case, glad it's resolved.  Happy new year!